# PHP: how to find and parse text between 2 conditions on ascii file

Tags: php, string, parsing

I have some text in a file (sample.txt) which I need to parse in PHP. It's structure is:

```
--Forwarded Message Attachment--
To: sample@sample.org
Subject:  W W Cadena
Date: Thu, 15 Nov 2012 19:33:10 -0600
From: sample@gmail.com


Nombre y Apellido       W w c
Email       sample@gmail.com
Edad        27
 México
Ciudad      Sabinas
hi there!



--Forwarded Message Attachment--
To: sample@sample.org
Subject: Z M
Date: Thu, 15 Nov 2012 18:44:30 -0600
From: sample@gmail.com


Nombre y Apellido       Zaida Macias
Email       sample@gmail.com
Edad        28
 México
Ciudad      tijuana
hi there!
hi there!




--Forwarded Message Attachment--
To: sample@sample.org
Subject: W W Cadena
Date: Thu, 15 Nov 2012 19:33:10 -0600
From: sample@gmail.com


Nombre y Apellido       W w c
Email       sample@gmail.com
Edad        27
 México
Ciudad      Sabinas
:D
```

I have already substracted:
- Nombre y Apellido
- Email
- Edad
- Ciudad

What I don't know how to do, is parse the following section, which is "message". I was thinking in reading line by line until "--" is found, which would be next block of data.

Got stucked in that part, using:

```
$line = fgets($fh); 
$incioLine = "--";
$mensaje ="";

$check =substr ($line, 0,1 );
    if ($check != $incioLine){
        $mensaje .= $line;
    }
```

however "mensaje" appends all of my data.

Would appreciate help, regards.

Comment: Try `$check =substr ($line, 0,2);` if you want to get `--`.  Maybe http://php.net/mailparse is helpful too

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$check = substr($line, 0, 2);
```

That should work.
You needed 2 chars.